# Entity Framework Command Intercept change context connection string

Tags: entity-framework-6, connection-string, interceptor

**Goal**:

fall back to the backup database when the main one is not reachable / down.

**Current implementation**:

when issue is detected, use class implementing *IDbCommandInterceptor* to change connection string to fallback server.

1. Close connection on the intercepted context.
2. Change connectionstring.
3. Open connection.

This works fine with *ReaderExecuting*, but doesn't with *NonQueryExecuting*. I can see that connection to the fallback server is open and looks fine, but I get the following during *context.SaveChanges()*:

**The underlying provider failed on Commit.**

**InnerException:** Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connection

**UPDATE:**
After looking a bit more into this I see that the issue happens within the transaction which is created by SaveChanges(). Closing connection on context results in throwing exception by the transaction object on commit. I couldn't find the way to change the connection or connection string for this transaction. Disposing it at the ConnectionGetting() using  IDbTransactionInterceptor and creating new transaction on context didn't help , it would still proceed to trying to commit (probably a race condition and not a good way to do this anyway).
ChangeDatabase() wouldn't seem to work as the connection should be to the same server.

**So the question is now:** is there a way to change connection / connection string for an existing transaction?

*StackTrace:*

```
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionInterceptionContext.WithConnection(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionDispatcher.Commit(DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
```

Comment: The answer well might have been staring at me in the face all along: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionInterceptionContext.WithConnection(DbConnection connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place to change the connection string is in implementing *Opening()* of *IDbConnectionInterceptor* interface. This works for simple reads, writes and transactions.
Implementing *IDbCommandInterceptor* members is useful for the complete solution while dealing with individual sql command behavior.